# Getting this error: angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

Im not able to solve this issue, help me! I tried lot of thing but didn't get the proper solution. I tried to debug but i really don't know how to debug angularjs application. is it loading issue or what i dont know?

```js
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config("$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
                when("/services",{
                   templateUrl: "services.html", 
                   controller: "servicesController" 
                }).
                when("/aboutMe",{
                   templateUrl: "aboutMe.html", 
                   controller: "aboutMeController" 
                }).
                when("/products",{
                   templateUrl: "products.html", 
                   controller: "productsController" 
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: "/products"
                });
});

mainApp.controller("productsController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.msg = "Product scope...";
}]);

mainApp.controller("aboutMeController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.msg = "About Me scope...";
}]);

mainApp.controller("servicesController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.msg = "Services scope...";
}]);
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Example</title>
      <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      
   </head>
   
   <body>
     <div ng-app='mainApp'>
      <h2>Select the page:</h2>
      <ul>
          <li><a href='#products.html'>Products</a></li>
          <li><a href='#services.html'>Services</a></li>
          <li><a href='#aboutMe.html'>About Me</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div ng-view></div>
         
      <script type = "text/ng-template" id = 'products.html'>
        <h1>Welocme to : {{msg}}</h1>   
      </script>

      <script type = "text/ng-template" id = 'services.html'>
        <h1>Welocme to : {{msg}}</h1>   
      </script>

      <script type = "text/ng-template" id = 'aboutMe.html'>
        <h1>Welocme to : {{msg}}</h1>   
      </script>
     </div>
     <script src = "js/mainApp.js"></script>
      <script src = "js/studentController.js"></script>
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: Use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` and you will get a better error message.

Comment: Please create a demo that reflects the current state on a site like Plunker (https://plnkr.co/). That way we can help figure out what is going on.

Comment: Could you show  studentController.js code? Does this Ctrl have injections?

Comment: Here is the code :

https://plnkr.co/edit/2udTtBJFaABreuJo9C1M?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forgot the brackets here:

```
mainApp.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
            when("/services",{
               templateUrl: "services.html", 
               controller: "servicesController" 
            }).
            when("/aboutMe",{
               templateUrl: "aboutMe.html", 
               controller: "aboutMeController" 
            }).
            when("/products",{
               templateUrl: "products.html", 
               controller: "productsController" 
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/products"
            });
}]);
```

Also I found a problem with links. This is the right way:

```
 <ul>
      <li><a href='#/products'>Products</a></li>
      <li><a href='#/services'>Services</a></li>
      <li><a href='#/aboutMe'>About Me</a></li>
  </ul>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/tlVxSy1U4pTzvobQJby6?p=preview

Comment: I dont konw that :(, but i got it :), thanks @tasseKATT.

Answer (score -3):

I think you forgot to add the scripts of your controllers in the html body :

```
<script src = "js/servicesController.js"></script>
<script src = "js/aboutMeController.js"></script>
<script src = "js/productsController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for your replay. But I've put entire code in one js -  <script src = "js/mainApp.js"></script> only